# Create HTML Table & Populate From Javascript Search

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary, filter, frontend

I'd like a way, in one function, to both search through an object array and create the right amount of HTML rows to populate with this search data.

Currently, I have an object array:

```
const coworkerDB = [
  {
    id: "id",
    firstName: "First Name",
    LastName: "Last Name",
    Role: "Role",
    Notes: "Notes"
  }...
```

that i'm creating an HTML table for when the DOM loads with:

```
(function tableMaker() {
  let table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  for (let i = 1; i < coworkerDB.length; i++) {
    //create new row
    let newRow = table.insertRow();
    let data = Object.values(coworkerDB[i]);
    for (let j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
      //create new cell
      let cell = newRow.insertCell(j);

      //add value to cells
      cell.innerHTML = data[j];
    }
  }
})();
```

Then onkeyup, I'm filtering this rendered data with:

```
function searchFunction() {
  let input,filter,table,tr,firstName,lastName,
    firstNameValue,
    lastNameValue;

  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (let i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    firstName = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1]; 
    lastName = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
    if (firstName || lastName) {
      firstNameValue = firstName.textContent || firstName.innerText;
      lastNameValue = lastName.textContent || lastName.innerText;
      if (
        firstNameValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 ||
        lastNameValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1
      ) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This table is expected to get bigger and I don't want to have to render all of the data to the page and then filter the results. I would like to be able to search through the data directly from the array, insert the correct number of rows, and map the search results to the table.

This is part of a small internship project and this is how the data is given. there is no relational DB.

Here is the html table just in case it helps:

```
       <div class="table-data">
          <table id="myTable">
            <tr>
              <th>id</th>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th>Role</th>
              <th>Notes</th>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
```

I've been looking for the best way to go about this and am leaning towards a map method that's a variation of a combination of both of the functions I have already. Does anyone know of a best practice way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I think Array.filter() is what you're looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: got it thanks!
I'll post the solution once it gets back from QA